# Regex find matches without in \n\n in between

Tags: regex

I am new to regex and could use some help. Each block is separated by two new line characters `\n\n`. I need to get the amount of dogs but only if that block contains a medium sized dog

I have the string

```
"4211 dogs ate 2 pounds
    chris (large)

3454 dogs ate 8 pounds
    john (medium)
    alex (small)

4211 dogs ate 2 pounds
    morgan (small)
"
//regex \d+(?=\sdogs\sate\s\d+\spounds[\s\S]*(?!\n\n)\(medium\))
```

using this regex:
`\d+(?=\sdogs\sate\s\d+\spounds[\s\S]*(?!\n\n)\(medium\))`
almost works. But the problem with it is that when it finds the pattern `\n\n` it doesn't stop until it finds the last occurrence of `\n\n`. I need it to stop when it finds the first occurrence of `\n\n` not the last, in order to prevent it from finding patterns in other blocks.

Comment: Which programming language do you use?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```
^                 # match the start of the line in multiline mode
(?P<amount>\d+)   # capture the number of dogs
(?:(?!^$)[\s\S])+ # do not overrun an empty line, matching every character
\(medium\)        # look for (medium)
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/GD5eT1/1/) (and mind the modifiers!).

---

An alternative solution would be to split on empty lines (`^$` with the `multiline` flag set) and check for `(medium)` in the resulting blocks.

Comment: @HarrisonSchultz: Glad to help.

Comment: @HarrisonSchultz: Nevertheless, please add the programming language used.

Answer (score 1):

PCRE with a capture group:

```
(?m)^(\d+) dogs ate \d+ pounds\n(?>.+\n)*?.*\(medium\)
```

without:

```
(?m)^\d+(?= dogs ate \d+ pounds\n(?>.+\n)*?.*\(medium\))
```

Javascript/Python with a capture group:

```
(?m)^(\d+) dogs ate \d+ pounds\n(?:.+\n)*?.*\(medium\)
```

without:

```
(?m)^\d+(?= dogs ate \d+ pounds\n(?:.+\n)*?.*\(medium\))
```

The key with these patterns is that each eventual line before `(medium)` is described using `.+` that enforces at least one character (in other words, it isn't a blank line).

Comment: I like this one as well (+1) as it requires less steps than mine.

Comment: @Jan: Thanks, note that anchoring the pattern *(in particular before a non-literal)* makes a huge difference.

Comment: As you see, I did anchor my expression as well - the difference lies in the tempered greedy token which is of course more "expensive" than `.+`.

Comment: I didn't see. Indeed `.+` is faster. To emulate the atomic group in Javascript and Python, you can also rewrite `(?>.+\r?\n)*?` as `(?:(?=(.+\r?\n))\2)*?`.